# removing all the commits added by a merge?

Tags: git

If you revert a merge commit a new commit will be created that undoes all the all the commits that the merge added. But what if you'd like to remove those commits all together?

I accidentally merged a development branch into master and pushed it. Because I pushed it I can't do `git reset --hard`, `git reset --soft` locally. The problem now is that if I merge the master branch into the development branch I'll have a bunch of merge conflicts because of the revert commit. I suppose I could revert the revert prior to merging but I'd rather those commits not even be there.

I don't mind doing `git push origin --force master` but at the moment I don't have anything that would even benefit from that.

Comment: Probably you can do something like `git push origin -f master~2`? Or find the first revision before the merge and reset your local branch to that and do a force-push.

Comment: "Because I pushed it I can't do git reset --hard, git reset --soft locally." well yes you can. "I don't mind doing git push origin --force master but at the moment I don't have anything that would even benefit from that." yes you have: first reset locally to before the merge, then force-push.

Comment: "because of the revert commit" What revert commit? You said you merged. You never said you actually reverted anything. Please show the actual commands you actually gave.

Comment: Note that when `git merge` does a true merge, it only adds *one* commit, specifically the merge commit. That one commit has two parents: the commit that was the tip before the merge, and the merged-in commit. Removing the merge commit suffices. When `git merge` does a fast-forward instead of a merge, it adds *no* commits; it merely updates the current *branch name* to point to a later commit. Here you must move the branch name back to the original commit. Fortunately its hash ID is available in the reflogs, both for `HEAD` and for the branch in question, so use those to find it.

Answer (score 0):

First : spot the commit you want to return to. Use :

```
git log --oneline --graph master
```

and spot the `<sha>` of the commit you want to return to (if I understood correctly: the first parent of the merge commit)

- to roll back your local branch :

```
git reset --hard <sha>
```

(warning : use the `--hard` option of git reset only on a clean repository, uncommitted changes will be deleted without a way to come back to them)

- to roll back the remote branch :

if you have rolled back your local branch :

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

note that you can roll back the remote branch without modifying your local branch :

```
git push --force-with-lease origin <sha>:master
```